# How to fit horizontal ScrollView to content's height?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a horizontal scroll view with a `LazyHStack`. How do I size the scroll view to automatically fit the content inside?

By default, ScrollView takes up all the vertical space possible.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var numbers = 1...100
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            LazyHStack {
                ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) {
                    Text("\($0)")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### This code can be MUCH better

### I have show it as BASE for your final solution

But it works

[image]

```
struct ContentView1111: View {
    var numbers = 1...100
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            FittedScrollView(){
                AnyView(
                    LazyHStack {
                        ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) {
                            Text("\($0)")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
            // you can see it on screenshot - scrollView size 
            .background(Color.purple) 
        
            Spacer()
        }
         // you can see it on screenshot - other background
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}

struct HeightPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 40
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct FittedScrollView: View {
    var content: () -> AnyView
    
    @State private var contentHeight: CGFloat = 40
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                content()
                    .overlay(
                        GeometryReader { geo in
                            Color.clear
                                .preference(key: HeightPreferenceKey.self, value: geo.size.height)
                        })
            }
            .frame(height: contentHeight)
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(HeightPreferenceKey.self) {
            contentHeight = $0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was almost a good solution, it kinda works, however the moment you have more complex views, it tends to cause clipping behind other views.

Comment: As seen here, it should have a label underneath and a complete circle. https://imgur.com/a/KIcdihd

Comment: @xTwisteDx as I have told in my answer - this is base for final solution. Code must be much better